# Parsing error for enclosing div element(undetermined JSX syntax)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**** So this is what terminal shows me ****

```
./src/card.js
  Line 9:9:  Parsing error: Unterminated JSX contents

   7 |                  <h2>john doe</h2>
   8 |                  <p>johndoe@gmail.com</p>
>  9 |          </div>
     |                ^
  10 |  );
  11 | }
  12 | export default card;
```

**** this is the code that i'm running using react, I don't why its showing error even though i have enclose it properly****

1.This is card.js file -->

```
import React from 'react';

const card=()=>{
    return(
        <div>
            <img src="" alt="roboIMG">
            <h2>john doe</h2>
            <p>johndoe@gmail.com</p>
        </div>
    );
}
export default card;
```

2.This is index.js code-->

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import card from './card';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<card/>, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `<img>` tag need to be closed:

```
import React from 'react';

const card=()=>{
    return(
        <div>
            <img src="" alt="roboIMG" />
            <h2>john doe</h2>
            <p>johndoe@gmail.com</p>
        </div>
    );
}
export default card;
```

check out this [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#specifying-the-react-element-type) on JSX

Answer (score 3):

Yout `<img src="" alt="roboIMG">` tag doesnot have a closing jsx.

use `<img src="" alt="roboIMG" />` its a self-closing tag element.

Answer (score 1):

Your code have an error as in react you just can't use `img` tag without closing it as its not a simple html. You have to close it like `<img src="" alt="roboIMG" />`